# images right next to each other in HTML

Tags: html

I have this HTML file whןch suppose to duplicate
an image and put it right next to the original.
so you get the same image twice, sort of connected
it does'nt work for some reason:
duplicate

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648852071390-7a17e3f2580a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648852071390-7a17e3f2580a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you
I was expecting an image to duplicate
but it does not work

Comment: set an max-width to the images :)

Answer (score 0):

It does work. As Victor Svensson mentioned the comments, one way you could fix this is by setting a max width for the images.

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648852071390-7a17e3f2580a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648852071390-7a17e3f2580a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer can be a bit unrelated to your case, but still, it works as you described.

Add a CSS rule `float: left` which puts all the elements just right next to each other. The image you're using is too big, so you might consider specifying the width of the photo by adding one more rule called `width:`  and the value you need.

You can add those rules in three ways: by adding them in the `style` attribute

```
<img style="float: left; width: 480px;" src="...">
```

or by creating a `<style>` tag in your HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .my-imgs {
            float: left;
            width: 480px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="my-imgs" src="...">
    </body>
</html>
```

or by creating a CSS-file, linking it to your HTML

Your HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="my-imgs" src="...">
    </body>
</html>
```

Your CSS file (styles.css in this case, placed in the same folder as your html file)

```
.my-imgs {
   float: left;
   width: 480px;
}
```

Comment: ok, where do I write it though? it is an HTML file in PyCharm –

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to just add `style="float: left; width: 480px;"` between `<img` and `src="..."`

Comment: I've noticed that `float: left` is actually isn't necessary here. You can add `style="max-width: 480px;` instead, as Victor Svensson mentioned

Comment: well it doesn't show the pictures, even when I change it. do you know were can I define?   : img {
  max-width: 50%;
}

Comment: Um, I guess I'll need some additional information on this. Can you please share some screenshots with the algorithm of your exact actions, please? Like, what did you exactly do with my answer?